# Definition about probability mass function by Rober V. Hogg

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

The following definition of pmf is on page51 from Probability and statistical inference by Robert V. Hogg, etc.

The pmf $f(x)$ of a discrete random variable X is a function that satisfies the following properties:
(a)$f(x)\gt 0, x\in S;$
(b)$\sum_{x\in S}f(x)=1;$
(c)$P(X\in A)=\sum_{x\in A}f(x),$    where $A\subset S$.

My question is about part(c). X is a random variable, and A is a subset of sample space S, how can $X\in A$. Moreover, how can ${x\in A}$?

In my opinion, the LHS of part(c) just means that we want to compute the probability of a single event, and the RHS of part(c) just means that we sum up all the related possibilities that we need.

For example, if X: numbers of the sum of a fair six-side dice. Then P(X=3)=P({(1,2),(2,1)})=1/36+1/36=2/36, where A is a subset of S.

Am I right? And could someone explain more about part(c)? It's better if someone can give me an example.

Answer (score 1):

*My question is about part(c). X is a random variable, and A is a subset of sample space S, how can X∈A?*: X takes one of several outcomes. $X\in A$ simply means that that outcome is in the set A, so the notation is correct.

*Moreover, how can ${{x} \in A}$?*: Again, this notation is saying all of the outcomes x that are in A (A is an event and a subset, so it is a set of outcomes).

*In my opinion, the LHS of part(c) just means that we want to compute the probability of a single event, and the RHS of part(c) just means that we sum up all the related possibilities that we need.*

*For example, if X: numbers of the sum of a fair six-side dice. Then P(X=3)=P({(1,2),(2,1)})=1/36+1/36=2/36, where A is a subset of S.*

*Am I right?*: Yes, you are right. The example you provided suffices as an example of the answer to the next question: *And could someone explain more about part(c)? It's better if someone can give me an example*

I think the main point to answer here is that X is a single outcome, a single element, so you want to say that the element is *in* the set A, not a subset of A. Hope this helps clarify things.

Comment: 1. So for $X\in A$, it just means that we collect all the outcomes that we want to express event A ( in my example are (1,2) and (2,1) ), right? 2. According to your last paragraph, so for part(c), we won't have things like P(X<2), it just can be P(X=n), for some n, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'collect'. Let me try and rephrase what I stated: as we are talking about a random experiment here, $X \in A$ means that X - which depends upon the outcome of the experiment - is one of the outcomes in the event A (A is a set of outcomes of the sample space corresponding to the event A). I'm not clear on your second question. You can definitely have $P(X<2)$ be meaningful. To keep things simple I will borrow your example with the sum of the fair dice. The event $X<2$ means that sum of the dice must be less than 2. In this case, that's not possible, so $P(X<2)=0$.

Comment: So to better answer your first question using the dice example, Let $A$ be the event that the sum of the dice is 3. Thus, $X \in A$ if and only if $X$ is $3$. If I instead say my event $A$ is the event that the sum of the dice is greater than $4$, then $X\in A$ corresponds to $X=5$ and $X=6$. Thus when $X=1,2,3,$ or $4,$ $X\notin A$, and when $X=5$ or $6,$ $X\in A$. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: So if X=5 and X=6, then how can we get the RHS form of part(c)? Could you explain more?

Comment: If the event A is the sum of the dice being greater than 4, then $P(X \in A)=P((X=5) \bigcup (X=6))=P(X=5)+P(X=6)=f(5)+f(6)$.

Comment: $f(5)+f(6)$ corresponds to the RHS of part (c). $P(X\in A)$ is just the LHS.

Comment: So LHS just means the probability of union of all the outcomes in S that are belong to A, and RHS means we sum up all the terms that we classify by (X=k1),(X=k2),...,(X=kn), where kn is the values that we need, and then compute its probability, right?

Comment: Again you are trying to restate in your own words which is fine but it's not simple to affirm your statement because the words you are using are ambiguous: "the values we need", "classify", etc. I think my previous comments have broken it down to a simple enough level that if you read the material it should make sense. I have given you directly what the LHS and RHS are for a specific example. If you have questions about using this definition in the context of an example I can answer that more directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion here is you have misquoted the author or are misinterpreting things. Let $X: S\to \mathbb R$ be a discrete random variable, i.e. takes values in a countable subset of the real line, say $E$. We denote the set $\{\omega \in S: X(\omega) \in A\}$ as $(X\in A)$. Put $f(k) = P(X = k)$ for each $k\in E$. By the axiom of countable additivity, $$P(X\in E) = P\left(\bigcup_{k \in E} \{X=k\}\right) = \sum_{k\in E}P(X=k) = \sum_{k\in E}f(k)$$
Of course this sum evaluates to 1 as $X:S\to E$, so $P(X\in E) = P(S) = 1$. And for any set $B\subset \mathbb R$, one has $$P(X\in B) = P(X\in B\cap E)$$
$B\cap E$ is countable, so by the same argument as before, we have $$P(X\in B) = \sum_{k\in B\cap E}f(k)$$

Comment: So in your answer $B \cap E$=$A$, and therefore $B$=$A$, right? (I mean $B$ is exactly the event $A$ in my question, right?)

Comment: @ElizabethAmanda No. What you wrote doesn't make sense unless $X: S \to S$, but this is not the case in general. Usually we have $X: S\to \mathbb R$, where $S$ is some abstract space.

Comment: 1. $X(\omega)$ are real numbers, how can they belong to $A$? $A$ is a subset of $S$. Could you explain more about this? 2. So what is the set in your answer that is equal to $A$ in my question?

Comment: @AndrewZhang I think $S$ in the original text is meant to be the sample space for $X,$ not the underlying probability space. Therefore $S\subseteq \mathbb R.$ Do these authors even mention the probability space? I don't know.

Comment: Oops my bad ... you are right @DavidK